# How the immutability of C# delegates (and strings) is implemented at the bottom?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, delegates, cil

In C#, for invoking a delegate in a thread-safe style, we can use the following code:

```
public static void TestInvokeDelegate1()
{
    CustomClass cc1 = new CustomClass("cc1");
    Action action = cc1.WriteName;

    Action action2 = action;
    if(action2 != null)
    {
        action2();
    }
}
```

Or, in C# 6.0 or later, we can also use:

```
public static void TestInvokeDelegate2()
{
    CustomClass cc1 = new CustomClass("cc1");
    Action action = cc1.WriteName;

    action?.Invoke();
}
```

As we know, these codes use the immutability of delegates to achieve thread safety. But how the immutability is done inside the .net compiler or runtime? I use the Ildasm tool to get the IL codes of these two methods:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  TestInvokeDelegate1() cil managed
{
  //        32 (0x20)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (class [System.Runtime]System.Action V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "cc1"
  IL_0005:  newobj     instance void ess_cs.CustomClass::.ctor(string)
  IL_000a:  ldftn      instance void ess_cs.CustomClass::WriteName()
  IL_0010:  newobj     instance void [System.Runtime]System.Action::.ctor(object,
                                                                          native int)
  IL_0015:  stloc.0
  IL_0016:  ldloc.0
  IL_0017:  brfalse.s  IL_001f
  IL_0019:  ldloc.0
  IL_001a:  callvirt   instance void [System.Runtime]System.Action::Invoke()
  IL_001f:  ret
} // end of method Program::TestInvokeDelegate1
```

and,

```
.method public hidebysig static void  TestInvokeDelegate2() cil managed
{
  //        32 (0x20)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "cc1"
  IL_0005:  newobj     instance void ess_cs.CustomClass::.ctor(string)
  IL_000a:  ldftn      instance void ess_cs.CustomClass::WriteName()
  IL_0010:  newobj     instance void [System.Runtime]System.Action::.ctor(object,
                                                                          native int)
  IL_0015:  dup
  IL_0016:  brtrue.s   IL_001a
  IL_0018:  pop
  IL_0019:  ret
  IL_001a:  callvirt   instance void [System.Runtime]System.Action::Invoke()
  IL_001f:  ret
} // end of method Program::TestInvokeDelegate2
```

I am not proficient in IL, but in these IL codes, what I seen are only copying reference to an object. By simply copying reference, the two variables are pointing to the same object, where is the immutability? There are no code to copy object data, how it is implemented? (Also the immutability of strings)

---

Additional text: codes writen by me for testing the immutability of strings and delegates:

**(NOTE: I know every thing in C# level of the following codes, it is writen by me to testing the immutability of strings or delegates. It seems that the object is copyed when the variable pointing to it is assigned to another variable. But in the IL codes, I cannot find the object-copy code. What I want to know is the internal implementadtion of the immutability, in compiler or runtime (clr) level. What happened at behind?)**

```
public static void TestStringImmutable()
{
    string s1 = "abc";
    string s2 = s1;
    s1 = "ab";
    Console.WriteLine(s1); //"ab"
    Console.WriteLine(s2); //"abc"

    s1 = "abcde";
    Console.WriteLine(s1); //"abcde"
    Console.WriteLine(s2); //"abc"
}
```

and,

```
public static void TestDelegateImmutable()
{
    CustomClass cc1 = new CustomClass("cc1");
    CustomClass cc2 = new CustomClass("cc2");

    Action action = cc1.WriteName;
    action += cc2.WriteName;
    Action action2 = action;
    action -= cc2.WriteName;

    action(); //Output: "cc1"
    action2(); //Output: "cc1" and "cc2"

    action -= cc1.WriteName;
    Console.WriteLine(action == null); //true
    Console.WriteLine(action2 == null); //false
    Console.WriteLine(action2.GetInvocationList().Length); //2
}
```

---

The **CustomClass** class:

```
class CustomClass
{
    private string m_name = null;

    public CustomClass(string name)
    {
        m_name = name;
    }

    public void WriteName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `As we know, these codes use the immutability of delegates to achieve thread safety.` I didn't know that. Can you point me to some documentation about this?

Comment: `In C#, for invoking a delegate in a thread-safe style, we can use the following code:` What do you mean by "in a thread-safe style"?

Comment: Is it possible to easily mutate an *instance* of a delegate?

Comment: `TestStringImmutable` in no way proves that strings are immutable. The code you are using there for strings will behave the same way for **all types**. If you create an object, assign it to a variable, then copy that variable to a second variable, then assign a new object (directly) to the first variable (i.e. you are assigning to the variable, not just setting a property on it) then the second variable will be different to the first. That isn't immutability - since _every_ type (even mutable ones) act like that.

Comment: Along similar lines, `action -= cc2.WriteName;` is not altering the object that is assigned to it - it is assigning a **new** value. It is equivalent to `action = action - cc2.WriteName;`. Note the **assignment**. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.remove?view=netcore-3.1#returns - note that it says it returns a **new delegate**. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/subtraction-operator#delegate-removal _Also, note that I never said anything about thread-safety or immutability. Since it is irrelevant to the code you presented._

Answer (score 1):

Check out my explanation:

```
public static void TestDelegateImmutable()
{
    CustomClass cc1 = new CustomClass("cc1");
    CustomClass cc2 = new CustomClass("cc2");

    Action action = cc1.WriteName; //Allocate action to an object refers to cc1.WriteName.
    action += cc2.WriteName; //Allocate action to an new object refers to cc1.WriteName and cc2.WriteName.
    Action action2 = action; //Allocate action2 to the object of action has been created above.
    action -= cc2.WriteName; //Allocate action to an new object refers to cc1.WriteName.

    action(); //Output: "cc1"
    action2(); //Output: "cc1" and "cc2"

    action -= cc1.WriteName; //Allocate action to null.
    Console.WriteLine(action == null); //true
    Console.WriteLine(action2 == null); //false
    Console.WriteLine(action2.GetInvocationList().Length); //2
}
```

Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense to me, it has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: @DingXin Read my comments above, then re-read this answer. Since this answer is correct.